# How do I give my sorcerer ice wings?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer

I'm making a gnome sorcerer starting at level 8, and I want to give her an ice theme. I figured I would start with the elemental bloodline(water). My problem is I want to give her wings shaped with ice or ice-like material for flavor purposes, but I can't figure out how to do it. Are there magic items that can simulate wings? Should I go with a different race/class?

Doesn't have to give her actual flight, but bonus points if you can work flight into it.

Comment: Do you require constant usage of wings or would occasional usage be enough?

Comment: Occasional usage is enough. Main thing is for the wings to be there. I had already considered illusions, but I just reeeeally want the wings to be real.

Answer (score 9):

Consider the [Lesser Wings of Flying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/wings-of-flying-lesser/), which costs 22000gp.

As Aaron said, you can reflavor this to be icy.

A much cheaper option would be the [Cap of Disguise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/hat-of-disguise/) for 1800gp, which could let you look like you had wings, so long as you keep them folded up.

The problem with these options is they don't give you a character that innately has ice wings; instead, they give you a character that had gone to a great deal of effort to *look* like they have ice wings.

One path to actually having wings is to have aasimar heritage -- see [Angel Wings (Aasimar)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/angel-wings-aasimar/) for example, though that doesn't kick in until tenth level. Perhaps you can work out a compromise with your GM where you spend the feats and have the wings now, but they're not functional until tenth level.

Answer (score 6):

The [Wings of Flying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/wings-of-flying/) seem to be exactly what you're after. The flavor text of the spell states they turn into bat or bird wings, however, there is no reason they couldn't be formed out of ice as there wouldn't be any mechanical difference. You could just ask your GM to have the cloak be a light blue and transform into ice wings instead.

I could not find any other ways to get wings with actual flight for cheaper however if your GM allows the [creation of unique magic items](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html) then you could create a similar item that uses the [Glide](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glide/) spell. The cost for it to be a command word item at the minimum caster level would be 21600, to craft it yourself it would cost 10800 if you take the right feats.

Here is my math to calculate the cost.

Spell level assuming a wizard is crafting the item 2. 
Lowest caster level possible is 3rd level. 
The calculation for a command word magic item is Spell level * Caster level * 1800

2*3*1800=10800, double that if you outright buy the item cause the cost doubles to purchase.

If you are just after the look then an item with an illusion on it would also work and would be much cheaper as you could just use the [Silent Illusion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/silent-image/) spell. A first level spell so the cost would be much cheaper, at only 1800 gold due to it only being a first level spell with 1 caster level needed. I would say this is reasonable cause there isn't really a mechanical benefit to this spell as all you get is a pair of illusory wings until you can get wings.

Comment: That almost works, except I'm starting level 8 with 33,000 gp and that item costs 54,000 gp. Got anything else?

Comment: @Visfarix I'm still looking, if I find anything else I'll edit it into the answer. I think there is a similar item but it only allows gliding, it's much cheaper though.

Comment: @Visfarix - depending on whether CWI is an acceptable feat choice, you might be able to craft them - 27,000 is expensive, but within your budget

Comment: @Visfarix I added more to my answer. Sorry I couldn't find anything more but everything I could find was beyond your reach at 8th level. Hope what I put helps.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle mysteries of Wind and The Dark Tapestry both contain a Revelation that grants flight for 1 minute/level (as a swift action!) which would be enough for brief displays of flight.

The Dark tapestry has the more cold-related(ish) theme to it of the two, and lets you spend all your usage of the wings for a day of Overland Travel from L11.

It shouldn't be much to ask for the cosmetics of wings when the revelation isn't in use.

Answer (score 2):

You can just reskin the [fly spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fly/) so it makes you look like you got ice wings. I can't see any reason why your GM wouldn't accept that.

If the duration is not long enough, you can wait a few more levels until you get [overland flight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/overland-flight/) (lvl 5 spell) which lasts for 1h/level (so you can reasonably have it all the time.